# Django queryset get max id's for a filter

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to get a list of max ids for a filter I have in Django

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   poo = models.CharField() 

Foo.objects.filter(name__in=['foo','koo','too']).latest_by_id()
```

End result a queryset having only the latest **objects** by id for each name. How can I do that in Django?

Edit: I want multiple objects in the end result. Not just one object.

Edit1: Added __in. Once again I need only latest( as a result distinct) objects for each name.

Something like this.

```
my_id_list = [Foo.objects.filter(name=name).latest('id').id for name in ['foo','koo','too']]
Foo.objects.filter(id__in=my_id_list)
```

The above works. But I want a more concise way of doing it. Is it possible to do this in a single query/filter annotate combination?

Comment: latest you mean by time? if you have a creation time, just order by date and get the first result.

Comment: Latest by id is possible, but that will give me just one object. I want multiple objects in the end result based on the name.

Comment: so order_by id.

Comment: @Bestasttung I want multiple objects in the output. Sorting by id and taking the latest won't work.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
qs = Foo.objects.filter(name__in=['foo','koo','too'])
# Get list of max == last pk for your filter objects
max_pks = qs.annotate(mpk=Max('pk')).order_by().values_list('mpk', flat=True)
# after it filter your queryset by last pk
result = qs.filter(pk__in=max_pks)
```

Comment: I just saw this. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: unfortunately i don't know, how add `annotate` column to the filter, but if you find the solution it will good, by the way, it is not bad as it look

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PostgreSQL you can do the following

```
Foo.objects.order_by('name', '-id').distinct('name')
```

MySQL is more complicated since is lacks a `DISTINCT ON` clause. Here is the raw query that is very hard to force Django to generate from ORM function calls:

```
Foo.objects.raw("""
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        `foo`
    GROUP BY `foo`.`name`
    ORDER BY `foo`.`name` ASC , `foo`.`id` DESC
""")
```